# Python socket server users are not able to connect after certain time

Tags: python, sockets

i'm new on stackoverflow and have a question.

I wrote a python websocket server and it works fine. But after a while new connections are not able. Chrome shows that the websocket stays on pending state. The server does not return any error.

My thoughts were that the unaccepted socket queue could be full, but even by increasing it to the socket.SOMAXCONN the server doesn't accept connections after a while.

My next thought was that the threads dont have enough stack memory, but also by increasing the memory the problem still exists.

Some code:

```
 def start_server(self, port):
        s = socket.socket()
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind(('', port))
        s.listen(socket.SOMAXCONN)

        while(1):
            try:
                conn, addr = s.accept()              
                threading.Thread(target = self.handle_client, args = (conn, addr)).start()

                self.LOCK.acquire()                    
                UserManagment.append(-1, conn)
                self.LOCK.release()

            except Exception as e:
                print("An error occured: ", str(e))


threading.stack_size(524288)
ws = WebSock()
ws.start_server(443)
```

I hope someone of you can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: You might be running out of underlying OS handles - either for the client threads or the sockets. Do you release them properly? i.e. do you call socket.close() at the end of the communication, and call thread.join() for all your threads?

Comment: I release them with socket.close() when they are not longer needed but most sockets have to have a long live period, I don't join the threads atm gonna try that later

Comment: How many sockets/threads do you create - tens, hundreds, millions? Can you elaborate on "after a while"? Do you see the same behaviour using different clients (other browsers? telnet?) Did you try to have a look at your process' state using e.g. ProcExp (from SysInternals)?